# Partial Objects in Ebean

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I'm trying to query partial objects using Ebean 2.3.3 in Java Play! Framework 2.2.1. For example, to get a list of records that only includes the fields `id`,`host`, and `publicKey` from the `instance_config` table, I use the following:

```
List<InstanceConfig> tests = Ebean.find(InstanceConfig.class)
                    .select("host,publicKey")
                    .where().eq("accountId", accountId).ne("host", "")
                    .findList();
```

This produces the following sql query, which I expected:

```
[debug] c.j.b.PreparedStatementHandle - select t0.id as c0, t0.host as c1, 
            t0.public_key as c2 from instance_config t0 where t0.account_id = xxxxxxxxxx 
            and t0.host <> ''
```

However, the same code also produces this query for each record in the table being queried:

```
    [debug] c.j.b.PreparedStatementHandle - select t0.id as c0, t0.host as c1, 
           t0.public_key as c2, t0.private_key as c3, t0.created_by as c4,
           t0.account_id as c5 from instance_config t0 where t0.id = xx
```

And the output returned from the server contains the full object, with all the fields.

I'm guessing these queries have to do with the [Lazy Loading](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/intropartialobjects.html) that Ebean does on partial objects?

I found in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250976/avaje-ebean-partial-object-query-disable-lazy-loading) that one way to get around Lazy Loading was to bypass Ebean all together and use the standard JDBC interface to perform the query. With the question being a couple years old, I wanted to repost to ask if this solution was still accurate?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say what your question specifically is but typically you want to use a partial object query for performance reasons and typically avoid lazy loading when you are doing it. So in your case perhaps you should simply remove the select() clause from your first query.

Lazy loading is not always bad but in your case if you are looking to avoid it simply remove the select clause and then all the properties will be loaded in the original query.

Now in the logs with summary level logging (DEBUG level on "org.avaje.ebean.SUM") for example:

```
... txn[2005] select t0.id c0 from be_customer t0; --bind()
... txn[2005] FindMany type[Customer] origin[5NLfz.CdTSLn.BvQ020] exeMicros[0] rows[0] name[] predicates[] bind[]
... txn[2006] select t0.id c0, t0.inactive c1, t0.name c2, t0.registered c3, t0.comments c4, t0.version c5, t0.when_created c6, t0.when_updated c7, t0.billing_address_id c8, t0.shipping_address_id c9 from be_customer t0 where t0.id = ?  ; --bind(1)
... txn[2006] FindMany mode[+lazy] type[Customer] origin[5NLfz.CdTSLn.BvQ020] lazyLoadProp[name] load[path:null batch:1] exeMicros[1079] rows[1] name[] predicates[] bind[1]
```

In the last log entry:

- +lazy : it's a lazy loading query
- LazyLoadProp[name] : this is the property read that fired the lazy loading
- origin[5NLfz.CdTSLn.BvQ020] : this identifies the origin query that the lazy loading relates back to

Now, not all lazy loading is bad but in your case we can see your table is not very wide (no that many columns in the lazy loading query) but we don't know the types (any big varchar columns in there etc). I'd guess and say that probably you should just remove the select() clause.

If you have DEBUG log level on for "org.avaje.ebean.SUM" then you can look for the +lazy queries, check the origin query that they relate back to and review if/where you might do better.

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using Ebean as long as you don't access any other fields.

The second query you see in the logs is executed as soon as you access any field *not* already present in the returned object. This seems to be Ebean's lazy load behavior per default.

I had the same problem, Ebean loaded all the fields after transforming my query results with `Json.toJson()`, this was accessing all my model's fields to create the JSON object.

I solved it by manually manipulating my results, making sure to not access any other fields beside the ones I fetched in my `select`.

For example:

```
List<InstanceConfig> tests = Ebean.find(InstanceConfig.class)
                .select("host,publicKey")
                .where().eq("accountId", accountId).ne("host", "")
                .findList();
// Accessing fields
String host = tests.get(0).host; // Doesn't trigger a new query
String publicKey = tests.get(0).publicKey; // Doesn't trigger a new query
String otherField = tests.get(0).otherField; // This will trigger a query
```

Ebean documentation on this topic: http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/query/features#lazy_loading