# Select particular columns in Ebean

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I want to select some particular fields from my database and send them to user as json but whenever i fetch data from database using ebean it selects all the columns

```
Optional<User>user= server.find(User.class).where().eq("name",username)
             .and().eq("password", DigestUtils.sha1Hex(password))
             .select("name").findOneOrEmpty();
if(user.isPresent())
   return ok(Json.toJson(user));
```

It shows all fields of table in json but i want only name field back.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31713062/1398418

Answer (score 1):

`id` column automatically in map when you select column.

Use `setDistinct(true)` before select column, it will only select name column

```
Optional<User>user = server.find(User.class).where().eq("name", username)
             .and().eq("password",DigestUtils.sha1Hex(password)).setDistinct(true)
             .select("name").findOneOrEmpty();

if(user.isPresent())
   return ok(Json.toJson(user));
```